# How to check if a number is within a group of non-consecutive ranges?

Tags: python, range

Question may sound complicated, but actually is pretty simple, but i can't find any nice solution in Python.

I have ranges like
`("8X5000", "8X5099")`. Here `X` can be any digit, so I want to match numbers that fall into one of the ranges (`805000..805099` or `815000..815099` or ... `895000..895099`).

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm confused about what `X` is...

Comment: I think he means X can be anything ...

Comment: -1 for confusingly worded question. +1 for use of the term "pythonic".

Comment: are you saying that 805001 and 815001 are both in the first range ("8x5000", "8x5099")?  Can you simply ignore the first two or three digits (e.g. by taking all numbers mod 1000) and get the result you want?

Comment: yes X can be any number.
i have to ignore only X symbol i can't ignore first one

Comment: @Zygimantas: "Any number" and "ignore" are contradictory. I assume you do mean "ignore", i. e. 805000, 815000, 825000 etc. are valid, but 805100 is not in your range `("8X5000", "8X5099")`.

Comment: Convert it to a string and use a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@TimPietzcker answer is correct and Pythonic, but it raises some performance concerns (arguably making it even more Pythonic). It creates an iterator that is searches for a value. I don't expect Python to be able to optimize the search.

This should perform better:

```
def IsInRange(n, r=("8X5000", "8X5099")):
    (minr, maxr) = [[int(i) for i in l.split('X')] for l in r]
    p = len(r[0]) - r[0].find('X')

    nl = (n // 10**p, n % 10**(p-1))
    fInRange = all([minr[i] <= nl[i] <= maxr[i] for i in range(2)])
    return fInRange
```

The second line inside the function is a nested list comprehension so may be a little hard to read but it sets:

```
minr = [8, 5000]
maxr = [8, 5099]
```

When n = 595049:

```
nl = (5, 5049)
```

The code just splits the ranges into parts (while converting to int), splits the target number into parts, then range checks the parts. It wouldn't be hard to enhance this to handle multiple X's in the range specifiers.

### Update

I just tested relative performance using timeit:

```
def main():
    t1 = timeit.timeit('MultiRange.in_range(985000)', setup='import MultiRange', number=10000)
    t2 = timeit.timeit('MultiRange.IsInRange(985000)', setup='import MultiRange', number=10000)

    print t1, t2
    print float(t2)/float(t1), 1 - float(t2)/float(t1)
```

On my 32-bit Win 7 machine running Python 2.7.2 my solution is almost 10 times faster than @TimPietzcker's (to be specific, it runs in 12% of the time). As you increase the size of the range, it only gets worse. When:

```
ranges=("8X5000", "8X5999")
```

The performance boost is 50x. Even for the smallest range, my version runs 4 times faster.

With @PaulMcGuire suggested performance patch to `in_range`, my version runs 3 times faster.

### Update 2

Motivated by @PaulMcGuire's comment I went ahead and refactored our functions into classes. Here's mine:

```
class IsInRange5(object):
    def __init__(self, r=("8X5000", "8X5099")):
        ((self.minr0, self.minr1), (self.maxr0, self.maxr1)) = [[int(i) for i in l.split('X')] for l in r]
        pos = len(r[0]) - r[0].find('X')
        self.basel = 10**(pos-1)
        self.baseh = self.basel*10
        self.ir = range(2)

    def __contains__(self, n):
        return self.minr0 <= n // self.baseh <= self.maxr0 and \
            self.minr1 <= n % self.basel <= self.maxr1
```

This did close the gap, but even after pre-computing range invariants (for both) @PaulMcGuire's took 50% longer.

Comment: +1 for extra speed. But I bet that if I had to read this code half a year from now, I wouldn't have the slightest idea how it works. :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker, maybe I'm a little too comfortable with list comprehensions (plus some math that's not frequently used). But you could re-write this approach, testing prefix range and suffix range, using idioms you're comfortable with and still wind up with a speedup.

Answer (score 1):

```
range = (80555,80888)

x = 80666

print range[0] < x < range[1]
```

maybe what your looking for ...

Answer (score 1):

Example for Python 3 (in Python 2, use `xrange` instead of `range`):

```
def in_range(number, ranges=("8X5000", "8X5099")):
    actual_ranges = ((int(ranges[0].replace("X", digit)),
                     int(ranges[1].replace("X", digit)) + 1)
                     for digit in "0123456789")
    return any(number in range(*interval) for interval in actual_ranges)
```

Results:

```
>>> in_range(805001)
True
>>> in_range(895099)
True
>>> in_range(805100)
False
```

An improvement to this, suggested by Paul McGuire (thanks!):

```
def in_range(number, ranges=("8X5000", "8X5099")):
    actual_ranges = ((int(ranges[0].replace("X", digit)),
                     int(ranges[1].replace("X", digit)))
                     for digit in "0123456789")
    return any(minval <= number <= maxval for minval, maxval in actual_ranges)
```

Comment: Perhaps quicker than searching through range is just doing chained inequality: `return any(minval <= number < maxval for minval,maxval in actual_ranges)`

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Of course, that must be faster by an order of magnitude. Thanks!

Comment: For the example range, @PaulMcGuire's patch runs in 38% of the time the original takes (just over 2.5 times as fast).

Comment: @jimhark: Thanks for measuring; I think the vast majority of the running time will be due to the generation of `actual_ranges`; if that  is done before, then the differences should be more obvious.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, generation of actual_ranges is part of it, but even if that's factored out as an invariant, your solution is left with 10 range checks while mine requires 2 comparisons. Well that and a division and a mod, two slow operators that could close the gap.